# ionic update navbar css

Tags: css, ionic3

Is there an easy way to modify the background colour the ionic navbar? I've tried the following, which when inspecting does seem to set the background colour, but it never shows (Its not overwritten)

```
ion-navbar {
    background-color: #525B92;
}
```

I've tried changing the text colour as well, but it also doesn't show. I've tried the css in the pages .scss file and the app.scss file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the background color of the navbar by

One way is styling `.toolbar-background`

```
.toolbar-background {
    background-color: #525B92;
}
```

Another is overriding in `variable.scss`

```
$toolbar-md-background: #525B92;
$toolbar-ios-background: #525B92;
```

Another is in html file

```
<ion-navbar color="primary"></ion-navbar>
<!-- or whatever color you made in variable.scss -->
```

Comment: Where can I find what they are actually called to change them? Like how do I know the toolbar is .toolbar-background

Comment: It is true that you can not see this in the [navbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Navbar/) and [toolbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/) docs.  However, by inspecting the `ion-navbar` element, you can see that there is a child div which can change its background. For overriding ionic sass variables (elements) you can search [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)